# Repeating All Line Items In PowerShell

Tags: powershell

## I have a script that reads data from two CSVs like the following:

$SORT variable:  CSV document

```
Auditor Mnemonic Start
Nate     BLDG1    0400
Nate     BLDG2    0430
Roger    BLDG3    0400
```

$SiteTML variable:  CSV document

```
SITE    tech1          tech2         tech3          supervisor
BLDG1   me@work.com    you@work.com  tom@work.com   dick@work.com
BLDG2   me@work.com    you@work.com  harry@work.com dick@work.com
BLDG3   roger@work.com sam@work.com  mike@work.com  dick@work.com
```

## The Idea

A popup appears for each mnemonic and asks if the site is resolved.  If Yes is selected, it is to move on to the next one.  If No is selected, it is to give the option to paste the error message and then it will automatically move on to the next one.

Once the auditor in-question's list is complete, the site is to report a list of all sites failing the audit in a popup (the actual audit is done via a webpage and the necessary data to run the audit is gathered in the `$site|clip` function).  After which, the script displays a separate website which shows a list of which sites succeeded versus failed [`START $THORSite`].

## Example

If `Nate` is selected, the script should show a popup that says, "Did BLDG1 complete succesfully?" and "Yes" and "No" buttons are available.  If the user selects "Yes" the script will move on to `BLDG2` and do the same action.  If "No" is selected, the script will ask the user to paste the error message and press `ENTER`, at which point it will send the email to the users associated with the mnemonic in `$SiteTML` and move on to ask the question for `BLDG2`.

Since the auditor for `BLDG3` is listed as `Roger`, and `Nate` is currently selected, it will ignore `BLDG3` and the list is complete.  The script should now compile a list of all sites where "No" was selected and present a popup that shows those mnemonics [the `$FailSite` section].

## Issue

Instead of completing the list, the script comes to the end and loops back to the beginning.  It is showing the correct sites, but instead of terminating the `ForEach` loop and compiling the error sites, it returns to the first site and repeats the entire list indefinitely.

Note:  I adapted this from a script I wrote for a single user.  This version is designed to have one master list for all users, and there is a user selection at the beginning [excluded from this question].  I can't seem to find what I've done incorrectly, even though I have my original script as well.

## Full script as follows:

```
$FHApage = "INTERNAL WEBPAGE"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$SiteTML = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\Site_Tech_Master_List.csv
$Date = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
$ThorSite = "INTERNAL WEBPAGE"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Data = Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\myFHA.csv
$FailSites = @()

$CurrentUser = ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:userdomain/$env:username,user").fullname
$Surname,$GivenName,$ADID=($CurrentUser).split(" ")
$TechName = $GivenName + " " + "$Surname"
$self = (([adsisearcher]"samAccountName=$env:USERNAME").FindOne().Properties.mail).replace('\W',"")
$smtpServer = "SMTP SERVER"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue


#Load the FHA webpage
START $FHApage

#Select Sort
$SortChoice = Read-Host "1.Preload
2.Day
3.Twilight
4.Night
5.Saturday
Select sort, press <ENTER>"
If($SortChoice -eq '1'){$Sort = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\GenData\presort.csv}
If($SortChoice -eq '2'){$Sort = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\GenData\daysort.csv}
If($SortChoice -eq '3'){$Sort = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\GenData\twisort.csv}
If($SortChoice -eq '4'){$Sort = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\GenData\nightsort.csv}
If($SortChoice -eq '5'){$Sort = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\GenData\satsort.csv}

#Select Technician
$TechChoice = Read-Host "1.Nate
2.Roger
Select technician, press <ENTER>"

If($TechChoice -eq '1'){$technician = "Nate"}
If($TechChoice -eq '2'){$technician = "Roger"}
ForEach($a in $SiteTML){

    ForEach($s in $Sort){
        $tech = $s.Auditor
        $site = $s.Mnemonic
        $time = $s.Start

        If($tech -eq "$technician"){
            $site|clip
            $intAnswer = $wshell.popup($site+" at "+$time+"
            Did "+$site+" complete successfully?", ` 
            0,$site+" status",4) 
            If ($intAnswer -ne 6) {
                $reason = Read-Host "Paste error here"
                $Today = (Get-Date).ToString('dd MMMM, yyyy, hh:mm tt')
                $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
                $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
                $msg.From = ($self)
                $msg.To.Add($a.tech1)
                $msg.CC.Add($a.tech2)
                $msg.CC.Add($a.tech3)
                $msg.CC.Add($a.supervisor)
                $msg.CC.Add($self)
                $msg.Subject = "Remediation Required:  "+$site
                $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
                $msg.Body = 'BODY DATA'
                $smtp.Send($msg)
                $FailSites += $site+"
                "
            }
        }
    }
}
If($FailSites -like '*'){
    $wshell.Popup("Remediation Email sent for the following sites:
    $FailSites")
}
START $THORSite
```

It's got to have to do with my closing brackets, or order of ForEach statements, but I can't find the issue.

Any assistance is appreciated.

## Update

`ForEach($a in $SiteTML)` is what is causing the continuous loop.  If I remove that loop, the system works, but that's where the email addresses for each site are stored.

What I need is to find a way to have the script reference `$SiteTML` where its `SITE` column matches the `$SORT` CSV's `mnemonic` column, and if they match, capture the email addresses from `$SiteTML` for that site as variables.

Comment: What is $siteTML?

Comment: @EBGreen $SiteTML is just a master list of technicians for sites.  All it does is associate a mnemonic with 4 email addresses which receive site updates if there are issues.  The email part seems to work fine.

Comment: So right now then you are saying to repeat the inner foreach for every technician listed in $siteTML

Comment: Where is $SiteTML getting it's value from? Could it be reading in the list more than once? Have you checked that it only contains one instance of each value?

Comment: @EBGreen It's written to only isolate sites for 1 technician.  The $SiteTML has all techs and all their associated sites.  When you're this far into the script, it's only pulling sites associated with the previously selected technician.  That part is working.  It just keeps looping through that technician's sites, instead of showing each once and terminating.

Comment: @Dave $SiteTML only has each site listed once.  It is a CSV containing a site name (mnemonic), then the three technicians and supervisor email addresses.

Comment: The list of sites being refrenced is the `$Sort` variable.  That's where the data that is repeating is stored.  It's a CSV with each site entered once.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the code you have provided does not accurately represent the logic flow in your actual script. Logic issues are difficult to diagnose without a [MCVE]

Comment: @EBGreen does my update help?

Comment: Hard to figure what the problem is. Everything looks like it should work . Can you show the code where you import the Csv for  `$SiteTML`? Have you tried setting a break point within the loop and checking the values of your variables?

Comment: @Dave I have provided the full code save a truncated user list and scrubbed data.

Comment: The `ForEach($a in $SiteTML)` loop is what's causing it.  If I remove that, it eliminates the loop.  However, I have to figure out how to load that since that's how the technicians get their emails for their sites.

Comment: I may have resolved my own issue here.  I got rid of the `ForEach($a in $SiteTML)` loop and replaced it with a `$SiteVars = $SiteTML | Where{$_.Site -match $site}` and then use the email addresses as `$SiteVars.tech1`, etc.  Will confirm and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForEach($a in $SiteTML)` was the culprit, causing it to loop through multiple times.

I was able to resolve it by eliminating the loop and replacing it with this:

`$SiteVars = $SiteTML | Where{$_.Site -match $site}`

Then wherever the `$SiteTML.SITE` entry matched the `$site` entry (which is `$Sort.mnemonic`), I was able to capture the associated entries in `$SiteTML` (the email addresses) and use them here:

```
$msg.To.Add($SiteVars.tech1)
If($SiteVars.tech2 -ne "NONE"){$msg.CC.Add($SiteVars.tech2)}
If($SiteVars.tech3 -ne "NONE"){$msg.CC.Add($SiteVars.tech3)}
$msg.CC.Add($SiteVars.supervisor)
```

Now I am getting the expected result of the techs/supervisors receiving emails for their site when an issue is reported.

Thanks to both Dave and EBGreen for offering assistance.